# Dockerized django app don't run in the browser

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm getting a problem when I run my docker image what I built with the next Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY Ski4All/ /opt/app/
COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/
RUN pip3 install -r /opt/app/requirements.txt

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/python3 /opt/app/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

With the command `docker run -p 8000:8000 -it --rm skiapi`

Everything run Ok and I receive the message about the server is running at 127.0.0.1:8000 but when I try to access via browser it says that the connection has been restarted and I can't access to the web. Any tip?

I got this logs from `journalctl -xe`

```
abr 26 17:04:51 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd53f322) entered disabled state
abr 26 17:04:51 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd53f322) entered disabled state
abr 26 17:04:51 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethd53f322) entered disabled state
abr 26 17:04:51 jhaos-m NetworkManager[1312]: <info>  [1587913491.9849] device (vethd53f322): released from master device docker0
abr 26 17:04:58 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaa75de2) entered blocking state
abr 26 17:04:58 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaa75de2) entered disabled state
abr 26 17:04:59 jhaos-m NetworkManager[1312]: <info>  [1587913499.0372] device (docker0): carrier: link connected
abr 26 17:04:59 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaa75de2) entered blocking state
abr 26 17:04:59 jhaos-m kernel: docker0: port 1(vethaa75de2) entered forwarding state
```

But I don't know if means something special also with systemctl status looks everythig correct. And I tried to docker logs < container > but I only executes django server and stop it printing nothing.

Thanks

PD: 
For some who is watching question and are starting with docker remember to rebuild the image when you make any change on the project, dockerfile, etc.. Some errors maybe can be for that.

Comment: can be a number of things... can you provide some logs?

Comment: @ivissani Sorry can you tell me how can I do it? I'm trying to get the logs with docker logs <container> but they give me nothing. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can try `docker logs --tail <CONTAINER>`. Try to access it on localhost and it should print out some logs

Comment: @AzyCrw4282I tried that but it only run the server and stops it quickly and  when I try to access it return me nothing.

Comment: Use `docker-machine ip default `to check for the IP, and use it to access instead of localhost.

Comment: I've no docker-machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your server on 0.0.0.0:8000 rather than 127.0.0.1:8000 as the later is not reachable.

0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.

Comment: It solved the problem thanks. How can my localhost have two IP addresses?

Comment: Think of it this way. All IP Routers (networking) are computers (hosts) with more than one IP Address. Even non-routers can have more than one IP address. Doesn’t even require additional physical NICs in the presence of virtual local area networks (VLAN). It’s even possible for a NIC to have multiple IP addresses in different network ranges assigned without VLANs, but in practice that makes it difficult for applications (Processes) to select source IP address.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for the answer it clarifies the question.

Comment: It's not that your physical host has multiple IP addresses (though it does), but that there are multiple "localhost"s (the container has an isolated network namespace and "localhost" means "this container").

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker-machine ip default` to check for the IP, and use it instead of `localhost`. 
Technically, the django app is served inside the container, not your local host.

So in your case, you should try `http://<ip from the command>:8000/`

Comment: In order to keep dockerfile independent of the system, machine IP should not be used. It should rather be 0.0.0.0

Comment: I couldn't use this commando cause I don't have any docker-machine running.